# Passing String to next XAML Page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am developing Windows Store App using C# and XAML. I would like to pass a string when moving from one page to another. For example,

```
 private void filterData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
           string str="mydata";
           this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(QualityRecordsResults));
    }
```

I need this str value in QualityRecordsResults.xaml.cs file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an overload of the [Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702394.aspx) method to pass the string to your view.

```
string str="mydata";
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(QualityRecordsResults), mydata);
```

Comment: You mean, this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(QualityRecordsResults), "mydata"); If so, how can I get the second argument in QualityRecordsResults.xaml.cs?

Comment: @Ramesh yes, this is the method i mean

Comment: The parameter is stored in the [NavigationEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationeventargs.parameter.aspx) that are passed to the Navigated-EventHandler in your QualityRecordsResults.

Comment: Yes. Using navigationParameter.ToString(); I am able to get the string. Thanks.